Sufficient condition for integral of sum = sum of integrals
Consider the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ where $x$ is a real number, and consider the integral
$$\int \left[f(x)+g(x)\right]\ dx$$
taken over some interval. Assume that this integral exists. Question: when can we equate
$$\int \left[f(x)+g(x)\right]\ dx = \int f(x)\ dx + \int g(x) \ dx \kern10mm (^\star)$$
One obviously necessary condition is that each of the integrals on the right of (*) exists, so that the equality is well defined. But is it sufficient?

Hint: yes it is. Show your attempts to prove it and where you are stuck, to prevent the post from being closed for lack of "context". First, include your definition of these integrals, be it Riemann or Lebesgue or sth else, and make the interval of integration explicit. Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions.

This might be a duplicate of some of these posts: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=linearity+of+the+integral

Whenever two of them are defined no? Also your obvious necessity isn’t one. What definition of integrals do you use`?

@julio_es_sui_glace can you elaborate on why it is not necessary? Does it make any sense to write an expression if the given expression is not defined? The integration I'm using is ordinary Riemann integration.

As long as they exist, it's enough. The integral is a linear operator. This comes from the derivative, its inverse, being linear. Suppose $F$ and $G$ are differentiable with derivatives $f$ and $g$, so that the limits defining their derivatives exist. By the algebra of limits, we can therefore split it into the parts that exist.
$$\frac{d}{dx}(F(x)+G(x))=\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{(F(x+h)+G(x+h))-(F(x)+G(x))}{h}=\left(\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}\right)+\left(\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{G(x+h)-G(x)}{h}\right)=\left(\frac{d}{dx}F(x)\right)+\left(\frac{d}{dx}G(x)\right)=f(x)+g(x)$$
Then what is $\int f(x)+g(x)\,dx$ asking? It's asking for a function which differentiates to $f(x)+g(x)$. Under the assumption that $F$ differentiates to $f$ and $G$ differentiates to $g$, we showed above that $F+G$ would differentiate to $f+g$. So the existence of $\int f(x)dx$ and $\int g(x)dx$ is enough to state that
$$\int f(x)+g(x)dx=\int f(x)dx+\int g(x)dx$$
That means we can construct counterexamples, by specifically making sure the pair of integrals we're adding don't exist.
$$\int0 dx=C$$
$$0=I_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)-I_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)\text{ where }I_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)=\begin{cases}
1\text{, }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
0\text{, }x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$
This is the indicator of rationals function. It's discontinuous everywhere, and Riemann integrable nowhere. The fact that these can't be integrated tells us that the integral can't be split.

Thank you, very nice proof
